# How to display value from yield return?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to display value from yield return ?

This my code :

```
public void getTypeRoomb1(string buildingNUM){
   StartCoroutine(getjsonroomtype1(buildingNUM));
}
public IEnumerator getjsonroomtype1(string buildingNUM){
        WWW request = new WWW(mainurl+"json_typeroom.php?building="+buildingNUM+"");   
        yield return request;    
        if (request.error == null || request.error == "")   
        {   
            var N = JSON.Parse(request.text);    
            if(N["type"].Count < 1){    
                notFoundText = "Not found";     
            }else{    
                yield return N; // Value return this line.    
            }    
        }else    
        {    
            Debug.Log("WWW error: " + request.error);    
        }    
    }
```

I locate line to return value.How do I display value ?

Suggest me plaese!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by DISPLAY?

Comment: I'm partial to the [lambda return method](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/207733/can-coroutines-return-a-value.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the "returning value" somewhere else, like get a reference to an other object and provide it with the value.

Coroutines in Unity can't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the yielded values through a dedicated method:

```
static IEnumerable LogValues(IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    foreach (var value in enumerable)
    {
        Debug.Log(value.ToString());
        yield return value;
    }
}

// ..
// Keep getjsonroomtype1 untouched
// ..

public void getTypeRoomb1(string buildingNUM)
{
    StartCoroutine(LogValues(getjsonroomtype1(buildingNUM)));
}
```